# Exclude files from being build in Debug

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

My WP7 solution has a Class Library which contains three big embedded resources. When the XAP file is generated, it takes quite a while to compress those three files and I would like to speed up the time required to build when I am in Debug mode (but not Release).

How do I specify in the CSProj that I don't want the file 2 and 3 to be build if I am building Debug?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\my-big-file-1.txt" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\my-big-file-2.txt" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Data\my-big-file-3.txt" />    
  </ItemGroup>
```

Thanks!

Comment: you may simply unload the library project while debugging the consumer project. Visual Studio will simply reuse the latest compiled. If you have modification, reload the project, compile, and unload again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use conditions in your Project Definition file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171455.aspx

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Data\my-big-file-2.txt"  Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' "/>
```